# Remove dropdown arrow in select

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I am doing my navigation menu as a select drop down menu. This was my css

```
#navigation {
    position: relative;
    margin-left:0;
    display: block;
    width:95%;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    /*background:url(../Shared/arrow.jpg) no-repeat right #ececec;*/   
    background-color:#ececec;
    border-radius:3px;
}

nav select { 
    display: inline-block; 
    width:90%;
    margin-left:2%;
    border:0 !important;
    position:relative; 
    margin-top:6px; 
    background:url(../Shared/arrow.png) no-repeat right #ececec;
    -webkit-appearance: none;          
    -moz-appearance: none;
    /*background: transparent;*/
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

My problem is that i am trying to show my own  arrow button , but it always placed under the original arrow button of select box. How can i change this

[image]

when change the width of the select as

```
  width:110%;
```

then output will be

[image]

Comment: have a look at this.. https://coderwall.com/p/w7npmq

Comment: Idea is to make the `select` element `width` more than the container element `width`

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I tried that, but the problem is that, when clicking on the select, then the dropdown window is very large

Comment: @Mr.Alien: i am edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :-

http://jsfiddle.net/Bpmhs/

```
<select id="style1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

    #style1 {
        width: 400px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        padding: 2px 30px 2px 2px;    
        background: transparent    url("http://media.miamiherald.com/static/images/redesign/dropdown-arrow-yellow.gif") no-repeat right center;
  }
```

Comment: still i got the same output

Comment: pls create a fiddle to clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

here is a codpen that demo's [a solution](http://codepen.io/brendosthoughts/pen/alysm)

the two key things you are missing are

```
#navigation{
   width: 100%;
     -webkit-appearance: none;

}
```

and then control the width of drop down in the wrapper in your case nav select

Comment: @Parvathiiiii okay? ... can we see what you have more then css ie. show live demo html and css. as both answers have done